# How to get css file from any file using php?

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

Here is what I want to state
I have this structure-

[image]

Now considering the directory I want to add the CSS file to all the files if I am using the **project-1 > sub-project > subfile.php** 
then I should be using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../asset/css/style.css" />`

Again if I use the **project-1 > file.php** 
then I should be using  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/css/style.css" />`

Now even if I use **index.php**
then it should be like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/style.css" />`

In short, I want it to access CSS file from any file dynamically. It's a type of autoloading whenever included.

I have tried something but it failed because it's not dynamic

```
$search = glob("asset/css/style.css");

foreach ($search as $ser) {
    $ser = $ser;
}

if(strpos($ser,"asset") !== false){
    echo "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='asset/css/style.css'>";
}else  {
    echo "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='../asset/css/style.css'>";
}
```

But the problem is it is not dynamic. Please provide a solid solution. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have domain name like:

```
domain.local
```

And your init style url looks like that:

```
href="asset/css/style.css"
```

Then you trying to access your project located under `proj1` directory:

```
domain.local/proj1/index.php
```

using same styles method the url will look like this:

```
domain.local/proj1/asset/css/style.css
```

**And they are no longer applied**

**Solution:**

You need to use relative approach.
Try this in your link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/asset/css/style.css" />
```

This will helps you no mater how many directories are, always grab styles using root as initial point.
Here are relative question: [Why the CSS style is not applied in webpages within subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806122/why-the-css-style-is-not-applied-in-webpages-within-subdirectories)

Comment: What problem are facing after?

Comment: @Askingtoprogrammers can you post any screens from the browser debug panel?

Comment: Now it's fixed I think because I was working on the localhost and the answer opened my and thanks for asking thank you

Comment: Sorry but I have less reputation